# How to vectorize this function to iterate over a particular column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

```
for choice in df["Num"].values:
    i=0
    delta=0.5
    z=[x for x in a["num2"] if choice-delta <= x <= choice+delta] #Selecting a subset from list of random numbers that lies within a range
    df["New Num"].iloc[i]=random.choice(z) #Selecting a random number from the subset to update the column
    i=i+1
```

Here df is a dataframe in which I want to iterate over a column named "Num". For each element in Num, I want to update it using random element from a specified bound from a dataframe named a.
Note: My dataset contains 150k values

[df["Num"]-Which needs to be updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQl9I.png)

[a["Num2"]-The random sample from which I have to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt60O.png)

Comment: What is your current output, and how is it wrong or different from what you expect?

Comment: Can you post part of your dataframe so we can try to build a proper answer? You are probably looking for creating a `function` and apllying it with `map`.

Comment: I have modified the code to include dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you are expecting.

But as you are taking random items from `a["num2"]` you can first use `a.sample(frac=1)` to shuffle rows before entering the loop.

Then, in order to change values in `df`, I would recommend to define a function `update()` and call df["Num"].apply(update) to reach your result.

Comment: I am trying to take random items from a range from a["num2"] that has been specified. And why to use update() when I am just using a single line function. I was thinking to use append.